# SwiftUI request to update App to last version

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to warn users when they use an outdated version of the App, pointing them in the right direction to upgrade, but all documentation I find is outdated from years ago.
Here is my failed attempt:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DeveloperView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    var appURL:URL

    init() {
        let url = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/es/app/id1552164068?mt=8"
        //also tried let url = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1552164068"
        //and also let url = "https://apple.co/2NM5DEK"
        self.appURL = URL.init(string: url)!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Button(action:{
                UIApplication.shared.open(self.appURL)
                //also tried UIApplication.shared.open(self.appURL, options:[.universalLinksOnly : false]) { (success) in }
            }) {
                Text("Please update to last version")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get in return:

> Failed to open URL itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1552164068:
> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_LSLine=229, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient
> openURL:options:completionHandler:]}

Comment: I think you are testing with simultor. please use device for testing. It will work fine.

Comment: You are right, Raja. Using my device was the solution